# Apache HTTPClient POSTs to REST service differently than cURL

Tags: java, httpclient, jira-rest-api

I am trying to hit a `REST API` with `Apache http client 4.5.5`.  I can successfully `POST` to the API using `cURL` like so:

```
curl -X POST --user username:password  --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@/path/to/file.json" https://some.restfulapi.com/endpoint
```

However when I try to POST to the API using Apache http client, it always fails with HTTP error code :`401 Unauthorized` when using the same credentials:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

CredentialsProvider credentialsPovider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsPovider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(request.getHost(), 443),  new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
                

HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsPovider);


HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(request.getHost()); 


// append headers
for(Header header : request.getHeaders()){
    httppost.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
}
                
if(body_entity.length()>0){
    // append the  data to the post
    StringEntity stringentity = new StringEntity(body_entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
    stringentity.setContentType(content_type);
    httppost.setEntity(stringentity);                                           
}


HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, context);
```

I have also tried adding the authentication directly as a header:

```
String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user + ":" + password);
httppost.addHeader("Authentication", encoding);
```

returns a `401 Unauthorized` too.

Furthermore, direct header variants:

```
- httppost.addHeader("user", "Basic " + encoding);
- httppost.addHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + encoding);
- httppost.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password), "UTF-8", false));
```

all result in `400 Bad request` response.

Using an HttpClientBuilder with CredentialsProvider

```
HttpClientBuilder clientbuilder = HttpClients.custom();
clientbuilder = clientbuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsPovider);
httpclient = clientbuilder.build();
```

also results in `400 Bad request` response.

> How do I create an Apache http client POST request that does what the
> cURL utility is doing?  What is cURL doing differently than Apache
> httpclient?  Might the encoding (UTF-8) be the issue?

Other posts and documentation:

- [cUrl to apache HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404135/curl-to-apache-httpclient)
- [convert curl to httpclient post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122035/convert-curl-to-httpclient-post)
- [Apache HTTP authentication](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

Comment: The authentication header is not called "user" but "Authentication"

Comment: @f1sh. I have tried that header label too.  Please see edited post.

Comment: It's not even `Authentication` but `Authorization`. It's called the Authorization header. Also, you are missing a space when you append the encoded credentials to `Basic` in your second example. It should be `"Basic " + encoding`

Comment: To help you find the answer, you should check how to log the actual HTTP request and compare it with what cURL produces. You will certainly see what's the difference there.

Comment: @Krisz. Even using `Authorization ` as header instead of `Authentication` - 400 response.

Comment: You could try to explicitly set the content-type header as you do with cURL, it might be required by the web service you try to call. But then again, I am not familiar with this Apache library, it might be set by default.

Comment: @Krisz Setting content type explicitly makes no difference.  If I set the user/pass header directly, always 400.  If I using `BasicCredentialsProvider` always 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("user:password".getBytes()));
```

plus the missing (and required - undocumented) header:

```
httppost.addHeader("Content-Length", json.toString().length);
```